# Connect Kubernetes service account to Google Cloud service account

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm developing a service running in Google Kubernetes Engine and I would like to use Google Cloud functionality from that service.
I have created a service account in Google Cloud with all the necessary roles and I would like to use these roles from the pod running my service.

I have read this: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform
and I was wondering if there is an easier way to "connect" the two kinds of service accounts ( defined in Kubernetes - defined in Google Cloud IAM ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct link. K8s service accounts are purely internal. You could try granting GIAM permissions to `serviceaccount:name` but that seems unlikely to work. More likely you would put the Google SA credentials in a secret and then write an RBAC policy giving your K8s SA read access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the topic which I have shared. You need to enable Workload Identity on your cluster and then you can annotate Kubernetes service account with IAM on google.

[gke-document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32697878)